# I have one array in javascript, i want to convert that as objects, here is my below code

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array output:

```
[ 33, [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

I want to convert that as:

```
[{contactId:33,groupId:1},{contactId:33,groupId:2}]
```

is it possible to do? with foreach loop or map function in underscore.js? if possible how to do? help me!

Comment: It's entirely unclear how you wish to arrive at the desired array. What if the initial array contains more elements?

Comment: just tell me in static way to do, i am a newbie :)

Comment: Static eh? `var newArr = [{contactId: oldArr[0], groupId: oldArr[1][0]}, {contactId: oldArr[0], groupId: oldArr[1][1]}]`

Comment: thank you for your response :), now i want to do that is dynamic way for my another project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var temp=[];
var firstElement="";
a=[ 33, [ 1, 2 ] ];
a.map(function(d,i){
  if(i==0){
    firstElement=d;
  }else{
    d.map(function(d1){
     var tempObj={};
     tempObj["contactId"]=firstElement;
     tempObj["groupId"]=d1;
     temp.push(tempObj);
   });
   }
});
 console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) You save my Day! :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your array `array` is always in the format of "an even number of items, where each even-indexed item is a contact ID, and each odd-indexed item is an array of group IDs", this should work:

```
array.reduce((prev, contactId, i, arr) => (
    Array.isArray(contactID) // check if it's a contact ID, or group IDs
        ? prev // skip the group IDs
        : prev.concat(arr[i + 1].map(groupId => ({ contactId, groupId }));
), []);
```